# How can I check my BeautifulSoup version and revert it to an older version?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup, and I am getting some htmlparser errors with start tags etc.

I read on crummy's site that one suggestion is to go back to an older version (3.08).

I am using Ubuntu, where I did:

sudo apt-get install python-beautifulsoup

to install it.

1. how can I check what version I have now?
2. how can I force a specific version using apt-get? (and how to uninstall what I have now)

thanks (i'm newish to ubuntu)

latest version of ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Belongs on ubuntu.stackexchange.com (and the first we'll ask you over there: what version of ubuntu are you using?  so make your question better as you post it over there by adding this obviously crucial info which you've omitted here).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i run in the same problem on mac osx 10.5
and i removed the current version of beautiful soup with

```
sudo apt-get remove python-beautifulsoup
```

then i installed 3.0.7 from [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.x/) address and all is now working fine.

To know the current version of you module:

```
import BeautifulSoup
print(BeautifulSoup.__version__)
```

Comment: but how can I install it using apt-get?

Comment: you may try: apt-get -v 3.0.7 but i doubt it will work (that would mean that the apt-get repository has a reference of all the versions)
however installing a package from a dowload is fairly simple and reliable (if dependencies is what you fear):
unpack,
cd to the directory and 
sudo python setup.py install

Comment: Of course, you should replace "BeautifulSoup" with "bs4", passim. See Alan Viars' answer.

Answer (score 20):

In Beautiful Soup 4 its like this:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__version__
'4.4.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question: at your shell prompt, type

```
python -c "import BeautifulSoup as bs; print(bs.__version__)"
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

```
import BeautifulSoup
BeautifulSoup.__version__
```

And for the second:

You can't. Maybe you should use easy_install or pip instead.